# How to remove text between two specfic words in python

Tags: python, regex, analysis

I have parsed a url to obtain its text using the beautiful soup package. I want to remove all text found in the terms and conditions section, i.e all words in the paragraph "Key terms: ......... T&Cs apply."

The following is what I have tried:

```
import re

#"text" is part of the text contained in the url
text="Welcome to Company Key.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Key Terms; Single bets only. Any returns from the free bet will be paid 
back into your account minus the free bet stake. Free bets can only be 
placed at maximum odds of 5.00 (4/1). Bonus will expire midnight, Tuesday 
26th February 2019. Bonus T&Cs and General T&Cs apply.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"
rex=re.compile('Key\ (.*?)T&Cs.')"""to remove words between "Key" and 
"T&Cs" """
terms_and_cons=rex.findall(text)
text=re.sub("|".join(terms_and_cons)," ",text)
#I also tried: text=re.sub(terms_and_cons[0]," ",text)
print(text)
```

The above just leaves the string 'text' unchanged, even though the list "terms_and_cons" is nonempty. How can I remove the words between "Key" and "T&Cs" successfully? Please help me. I've been stuck on this supposedly simple piece of code for quite a while now and it is getting really frustrating. Thank you.

Comment: can you add a ^ symbol at the start of your regex to have a negative look ahead, so that terms n cons variables gets only things which aren't filtered with regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag in your regex, to match newline characters with the dot.

**Method 1: Using re.sub**

```
import re

text="""Welcome to Company Key.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Key Terms; Single bets only. Any returns from the free bet will be paid 
back into your account minus the free bet stake. Free bets can only be 
placed at maximum odds of 5.00 (4/1). Bonus will expire midnight, Tuesday 
26th February 2019. Bonus T&Cs and General T&Cs apply.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"""

rex = re.compile("Key\s(.*)T&Cs", re.DOTALL)
text = rex.sub("Key T&Cs", text)
print(text)
```

**Method 2: Using group**

Match the text with a group and remove the text of that group from the original text.

```
import re

text="""Welcome to Company Key.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Key Terms; Single bets only. Any returns from the free bet will be paid 
back into your account minus the free bet stake. Free bets can only be 
placed at maximum odds of 5.00 (4/1). Bonus will expire midnight, Tuesday 
26th February 2019. Bonus T&Cs and General T&Cs apply.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"""

rex = re.compile("Key\s(.*)T&Cs", re.DOTALL)
matches = re.search(rex, text)
text = text.replace(matches.group(1), "")
print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.What if I have two paragraphs with terms and conditions written in each paragraph, and one paragraph with useful text between them. In that case, your code will remove the paragraph between them aswell. How can this be tackled?

Comment: you could create two capture groups: `"Key\s(.*)WORD(.*)&Cs"`  where WORD is some regex right before the start of the useful text. Then you could do two replaces as in method 2, using goup(1) and group(2)